# How to build a nested menu with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

Before I go into a custom implementation, I'd like to ask the community if there is any built-in helper for constructing a nested menu out of entities in MVC4.  I have a hierarchy of data like this:

```
> Folder 1
> Folder 2
>> Folder 2.1
>> Folder 2.2
>>> Item 2.2.1
>>> Folder 2.2.1
>> Folder 2.3
> Folder 3
```

And I'm thinking about passing an array of nested arrays (of nested arrays [of nested arrays...]) into the controller to build into a list of corresponding nested links.  Before I dive into this I have a couple questions:

1. What kind of tools are available to help with this, if any?
2. What data structures would you use if you had to build custom?

I'm totally new to MVC/C# so any suggestions/pointers would be awesome.

Comment: Is the data coming from datasource? Or it is static?

Comment: It's coming from a DTO, which I can build any way I wish from a POCO directly from the database.  So datasource, not static (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kind of tools are available to help with this, if any?

I personally haven't come across ready-made solution for this.

> What data structures would you use if you had to build custom?

Best bet is to build a custom class for this. Like a `tree` that has a `dictionary of nodes`.
You can build a custom one as below:

```
public class Tree
{
    private TreeNode rootNode;
    public TreeNode RootNode
    {
        get { return rootNode; }
        set
        {
            if (RootNode != null)
                Nodes.Remove(RootNode.Id);

            Nodes.Add(value.Id, value);
            rootNode = value;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary Nodes { get; set; }

    public Tree()
    {
    }

    public void BuildTree()
    {
        TreeNode parent;
        foreach (var node in Nodes.Values)
        {
            if (Nodes.TryGetValue(node.ParentId, out parent) &&
                node.Id != node.ParentId)
            {
                node.Parent = parent;
                parent.Children.Add(node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want more details, then [this link](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/mapping-relational-table-data-to-a-tree-structure-in-mvc/) has all you need.

Comment: Wow!  Awesome.  I didn't consider devoting a class to this.  Thanks Bhushan